# Correcting a table's projection in MapInfo

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

Occasionally I have a MapInfo TAB file that doesn't match up with others. Presumably this is because MapInfo is interpreting it as a different projection to the one it was saved as. I am also assuming that it is possible to have two TAB files of different projections in the same workspace and have them match up.

As far as I can see the only way to change a tables projection is to save a copy which doesn't seem to help me.

I there a way to switch projections on the fly? Or at least to find out which projection the TAB file thinks it is and which projection MapInfo is interpreting it as? Am I just being thick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also reproject / attribute another projection your Mapinfo datasets with the free and open-source ogr2ogr GDAL utilty :

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

An easy way to obtain that utility is to install Frank Warmerdam's Tools :

http://fwtools.maptools.org/

Answer (score 3):

MapInfo stores the projection information inside the MAP file. If the coordinates are correct, but you have wrong projection stored, it can only be corrected one way:
Export the table to MIF format, edit the coordsys inside the MIF and then import the file again.
After that MapInfo will take care of reprojecting the data on-the-fly if you want to show it together with datasets with other projections.

Answer (score 2):

You can check what the Map windows projection is by going to Map > Map Options and click the Projections button. This will also allow you to change the maps projection.

You can also check the projections of the tables by going to Table > Maintenance > Table Structure. Here you can check the tables projection.

You are correct, to change the tables projection, you need to save a copy and change the projection on the Save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to save a copy as (File->save copy as)
make sure to set the projection you want and save it.

Close the current file, then open the new one.

Note this is for Mapinfo 11.5

Answer (score 0):

In table structure > unclick "table is mappable" then click "ok" > then open table structure again and select a differrent coordinate system.
If needed > press "Create points" and select differrent columns for coordinates.